# custom validation attribute is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, customvalidator

**Hi i have a custom attribute**

```
public class maxlengthattribute:ValidationAttribute
    {
        public readonly int max;
        public maxlengthattribute(int _max)
        {
            max = _max;
        }
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (value.ToString().Length> max)
                {
                    var errorMessage = "Too many characters";
                    return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
                }

            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

**and i am using this custom attribute in the following model:**

```
public partial class Registration
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="You must provide your name")]
        [maxlengthattribute(5)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**But my custom attribute is not working. Please help me**

Comment: define **not working** !

Comment: the `Required` attribute showing validation message when i left the textbox blank but `maxlenghtattribute` is not showing any message if i try to input more than 5 letters in the textbox.

Comment: are you reffering to client side validation ?

Comment: @astian both client side and server side.

Comment: There is much to be done for the client side validation to work for this attribute, however, if you send back your model to the server, is the ModelState.IsValid - false or true ?

Comment: Custom validation will only be validated on server side (when the form is submitted / posted). If you want to have custom validation that validates on server and client, please check the [mvc foolproof validation](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/)

Comment: If you want client side validation you have to implement IClientValidatable interface while creating custom attribute class.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments stated there is much work to be done for client side validation to work. Your server side validation is 1/2 complete. First in your view you need a place to display your validation messages

**view**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Registration

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
    <input type ="submit"/>
}
```

then your post needs to redirect back to your view in the case of an invalid model state.

**controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Registration registration)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View();
    //do stuff when valid
}
```

Now when you do not post a name and/or have a name longer than 5 characters it will post back to the index view and display an error. (using your model and attribute listed above)